# Spring (JdbcTemplate)

Tags: spring

почему при использовании jdbctemplate.query, данные получаю в виде @b2a1bdf
 RowMapper вроде как используется и с остальными сущностями проблем нет.

```
List<Divisions> divisionses = jdbcTemplate.query(sql, (rs, rowNum) -> {

    Divisions divisions = new Divisions();
    divisions.setName(rs.getString("name"));
    divisions.setPf(rs.getString("pf"));
    return divisions;
});

return divisionses;
```

Comment: Что за вид такой? Где он такой? В `ResultSet`е?

Comment: Из описания вообще непонятно, в чем проблема

Comment: смотри, я получаю этот лист в контроллере, и далее, этот лист, передаю во вьюху, используется Spring 4 и thymeleaf. во вьюхе при выводе такое вот вижу, это ведь получается что при выборке не отрабатывает rowmapper?

Comment: Вряд ли. Скорее всего контроллер не умеет `List` передавать правильно. Что мешает отладчиком влезть в `RowMapper` и посмотреть правильно ли он поля вытаскивает?

Comment: Получается что при выводе во вьюху у вас выводится строковое представление `List`. Покажите код, как вы добавляете во вьюху данные из `List` + переопределите в вашем  классе `Divisions` метод `toString()`

Comment: передаем во вьюху <br/>   `@RequestMapping(value = "/reports", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index(Model model) {

        List<Divisions> divisionses = .getDivisions();
        model.addAttribute("formSubDivisions", divisionses);
        return "views/indexReports";
    }`

Comment: `<option th:each="type : ${formSubDivisions}"
                th:value="${type}"
                th:text="${type}">
        </option>`  выводим

Comment: всё, извиняюсь, моя вина...у меня в сущности два поля, а тут получается не указываю какое поле показывать.

Comment: у меня какие то проблемы с местным форматированием, за это тоже извините, новенький еще не освоился, вроде написано для того чтобы вывести код надо прописать две тыльды и между ними скопировать код, но что то не работает +)

Comment: `<option th:each="type : ${formSubDivisions}"
                th:type="text"
                th:value="${type.pf}"
                th:text="${type.name}">
        </option>`

Comment: Не тильда, а гравис, который на обратный амперсант похож. В общем, клавиша с тильдой, только с зажатым Shift